# How can I add icons for elements in qt listwidget?

Tags: python, qt, qlistwidget

[image: tool ui]

as given in the snapshot, I want to add respective color icons for the items in the listwidget, like the blue icon for blue.png, etc. How can I do it?

and after I drag and drop elements from available textures to selected textures, there should be an icon in that widget as well.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    ui_obj = TextureSwatcherUI()
    files = []
    for i in os.listdir("Q:/...../tex_source/"):
        files.append(i)
        list_item = QListWidgetItem(i, ui_obj.available_textures)
        list_item.setIcon("Q:/...../tex_source/red.png")
```

This is the snippet where I was trying to get all the files and add them to my widget, now I need to add respective icons next to them as well.

Comment: [`QListWidgetItem::setIcon `](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#setIcon)?

Comment: @G.M. i know it might be a simple method, but I am a total newbie to it and need to use it one of my task , trying to use it using python but it's throwing errors of QtGui not found when i am using this "listItem.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon())", if you can help me out with it that'll be great thanks.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to show your code and what you've tried thus far.

Comment: @G.M. I have added the required snippet of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create one Minimal Example to show how you can add Icon to `QListWidgetItem`

You should create one `QListWidgetItem` and set one **Icon** to it and name(text) and etc and then you add it in `QListWidget`.

you didn't have to add them by using `for` loop.

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication,QListWidget,QListWidgetItem
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    listWidget = QListWidget()

    #Resize width and height
    listWidget.resize(300,120)
    icon1 = QIcon("/home/parisa/ListWidget/check.png");
    listWidget.addItem(QListWidgetItem(icon1,"Item 1"));
    icon2 = QIcon("/home/parisa/ListWidget/crossout.png");
    listWidget.addItem(QListWidgetItem(icon2,"Item 2"));
    listWidget.addItem(QListWidgetItem("Item 3"));
    listWidget.addItem(QListWidgetItem("Item 4"));


    listWidget.setWindowTitle('This is Minimal Example')

    listWidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The Result:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add icons without Pyside ? As i am going to use it in various maya versions and pyside doesn't support all of them so there can be some conflicts.

Comment: @KartikeySinha yeah just import `QApplication,QListWidget,QListWidgetItem` and `QIcon` in the way that you know. code will works